# How to create Data Entry User Interfaces in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, data-entry

Suppose that you have a big Data Entry Web Application Like Microsoft **CRM**, what is the strategies and technologies that you follow to build a website like it?

*I don't want to use any Dynamic Web Page Generation software, because it have a lot of limitations.. 
Also I don't want to design every page and repeat everything*

what's the best approach? 
Any Ideas or Head lines on this issue?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Wael Dalloul - It appears that you DO want SOME dynamic page generation but have some concerns about the limitations. Which limitations are you concerned by. That is the only way we can know what to suggest to give you the power and flexibility you want.

Also, Can you provide a link to "Microsoft CRM Project". there are many applications that meet that name and we do not know which you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try frameworks such as MVC or MVP. ASP.Net Development is leading to that direction.

You can read some introduction here:
http://www.asp.net/mVC/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a really general question and is hard to provide much guidance without some specific details.  Is it an Enterprise App?  How will it be deployed?  Do you need to provide a Web Service Interface?  What sort of back end data storage are you planning on using? What sort of authentication scheme do you need?  And on and on .....

Here are some general guidance from the MS Patterns and Practices Team:

[Microsoft Application Architecture Guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673617.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673617.aspx)

[Microsoft Patterns and Practices Developer Home](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx)

Comment: Do you know Microsoft CRM Project?, I looked at their project it seems that they are using special way to generate the pages depending on XML files Dynamically.  
They are not designing every page and doing coding for every page, this what I want to know, leave the authentication, deployment...

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own standard format xml file that defines the index fields you wish to key during data entry. Your web app would then read this xml file for whichever document/data entry forms you wish to be working with at the time. This will allow you to dynamically read and create a form based on the fields specified within your configuration xml file for multiple forms.

Your view / UI could render the configuration file and dynamically display the data entry fields as text boxes at run-time or you could use a scaffolding application like SubSonic to generate classes / forms for you and then alter the forms to include validation and custom scripts.